# Runaway argument error when creating a macro for code that works outside a macro

Tags: macros, sagetex

I'm certain my problem is due to my almost complete lack of understanding of LaTeX's expansion rules...

I wrote some code, which uses the SageTeX package to keep track of a list of answers to homework problems and then print them all at the end. Here is an example of part of it:

```
\begin{sagesilent}
class AnswerList:
    def __init__(this):
        this.answers = []
    def _latex_(this):
        result = "\\begin{answers}\n"
        for answer in this.answers:
            result += "    \\item " + str(answer) + "\n"
        result += "\\end{answers}\n"
        return result
    def next(this, answer):
        this.answers.append(answer)
answerlist = AnswerList()
\end{sagesilent}
```

This compiles in my LaTeX document just fine. I then use other SageTeX commands to add answers (in order) to this object, and then print them all at the end automatically, and it produces the desired results. However, I was hoping to move all the programming into macros in a separate file to make it more reusable and to keep my LaTeX document clean. So, one macro I created was:

```
\newcommand{\makeanswers}{%
\begin{sagesilent}
class AnswerList:
    def __init__(this):
        this.answers = []
    def _latex_(this):
        result = "\\begin{answers}\n"
        for answer in this.answers:
            result += "    \\item " + str(answer) + "\n"
        result += "\\end{answers}\n"
        return result
    def next(this, answer):
        this.answers.append(answer)
answerlist = AnswerList()
\end{sagesilent}
}
```

I then include the second document into my first document (with an `\input` command) and call `\makeanswers` right after I enter the document environment in my main LaTeX file. I'm getting runaway argument errors when I try to compile the document.

Is there a way to create a macro that inserts this chunk of LaTeX code? There is probably a more LaTeX-friendly, less Python-dependent, approach to my problem here, but it is what I know...

Comment: As David says, a MWE would be nice. I have a feeling that this could be useful for me too, if I had some compilable code to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work with `sagetex`, but a pure LaTeX solution is probably best, and shouldn't be too difficult.  Here are some ideas on using `sagetex`, followed by a pure LaTeX solution.

Have you tried putting the `sagesilent` in an external file without wrapping it in a macro? I think that would work.  You will probably have to `\input` the external file from within the **body** of the document, because `sagesilent` doesn't seem to work in the preamble.

I don't have Sage to test with, but here's an equivalent with my [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package.  If you replace my `pycode` with `sagesilent` and `\pyc` with `\sagestr` (and maybe get rid of the `print()`), things will probably work, or at least be close.  My definition of the `\addanswer` macro assumes that your answers won't include `#` or `%` (or possibly a few other special characters for `sagetex`).  You should be able to put the class definition and macro definitions in an external file and then `\input` within the document **body** (again, `sagesilent` doesn't seem to like the preamble...incidentally, `pythontex` doesn't have that limitation).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\newenvironment{answers}{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
class AnswerList:
    def __init__(this):
        this.answers = []
    def _latex_(this):
        result = "\\begin{answers}\n"
        for answer in this.answers:
            result += "    \\item " + str(answer) + "\n"
        result += "\\end{answers}\n"
        return result
    def next(this, answer):
        this.answers.append(answer)
answerlist = AnswerList()
\end{pycode}

\newcommand{\addanswer}[1]{\pyc{answerlist.next("#1")}}
\newcommand{\printanswers}{\pyc{print(answerlist._latex_())}}

\addanswer{123}

\addanswer{345}

\printanswers

\end{document}
```

And here's an approach that doesn't need any external Python program.  You might be able to modify something like this for your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\storedanswers}{}
\newcommand{\addanswer}[1]{\g@addto@macro\storedanswers{\item #1}}
\newcommand{\makeanswers}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \storedanswers
    \end{enumerate}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addanswer{123}

\addanswer{345}

\makeanswers

\end{document}
```

Comment: Love the LaTeX-only implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It helps if you post complete documents rather than fragments, although I don't think I have that package, but if it is doing what I assume it is doing then something like this untested code will probably work.

```
\catcode`Z=0
\catcode`\\=12

Znewcommand{Zmakeanswers}{%
Zbegin{sagesilent}
class AnswerList:
    def __init__(this):
        this.answers = []
    def _latex_(this):
        result = "\\begin{answers}\n"
        for answer in this.answers:
            result += "    \\item " + str(answer) + "\n"
        result += "\\end{answers}\n"
        return result
    def next(this, answer):
        this.answers.append(answer)
answerlist = AnswerList()
\end{sagesilent}
}
Zcatcode`Z\=0
```